# run terminal commands from quicksilver

Tags: macos, terminal, quicksilver

I know there is a Terminal plugin for quicksilver but I would invoke terminal commands which basically just runs in the background and never popups a terminal window. is that possible?

UPDATE:

I have the following code in my applescript but its giving me an error:

```
do shell script "/path/to/shell.sh blah"
```

error:

```
curses.setupterm()
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database
```

Answer (score 7):

In Quicksilver you can use the action "Run Command in Shell", which is part of the "Terminal Module". The command is run without showing a window. Search on the quoted terms and you'll find some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Applescript is the simple solution, see:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2002/tn2065.html

Sample:

```
do shell script "ifconfig"
do shell script "ifconfig" user name "Anne" password "p@ssw0rd" with administrator privileges
```

Automator can also run shell scripts in the background.

If you are familiar with XCode, you can use NSTask with Objective-C.

Comment: I have a shell script which I can run from a terminal and it works fine but when I try to run the same command with do shell script "/path/to/shell.sh blah" it gives me the following error `curses.setupterm()
_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database`

Answer (score 1):

Hold on a sec, is your shell script a bash shell script? In your first line do you have:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

If not, add that line to your script.
Also instead of just

```
do shell script "/path/to/yourscript.sh"
```

consider this:

```
do shell script "/bin/bash /path/to/yourscript.sh"
```

Comment: its not a long running process. I basically have a cli todo script which I wanna use quicksilver to quickly add my todo items.

Comment: can you give us more info on what the todo script does?

Comment: all it does is add items to a sqlite database. So I execute a command something like 'todo -a blah' and it adds blah to the list.